# Architecture for building XML requests?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I'm writing a client tool that uses soap xml webservices (using CXF to autogenerate the classes from provided wsdl). I wonder which design is best to construct the xml requests I want to sent to the webservices. My problem is that the request to be send has to be formed of many different parts/objects. I'm looking for a clean way of how to structure the creation of these parts, that finally form the full request.

The request might be growing to 200-500 XML lines, so it is probably a bad idea to create these all in a single class.

To illustrate my goal, let's assume a request requires a `Person` object, and some params have to be set on that object like name, birthday, address etc. I could think of the following designs:

1) static utility that returns the constructed xml part

```
class XMLUtil {
    public static PersonType createPerson(String name, String birthday, Address Address) {
        //the xml person to send within the request
        PersonType p = new PersonType();
        p.setName(name);
        p.setBirthday(birthday);
        p.setAddress(address);
        //assume some more params, but the concept is clear I hope
        return p;
    }
}
```

2) static utility that adds the constructed xml part to the xml request

```
class XMLUtil {
    public static void addPerson(WebserviceReq req, String name, String birthday, Address Address) {
        //create person as above
        req.addPerson(p);
    }
}
```

3) non static service

```
class XMLService {
    private WebserviceReq req;

    public XMLService(WebserviceReq req) {
        this.req = req;
    }

    public void createPerson(String name, String birthday, Address Address) {
        //create person as above
        req.addPerson(p);
    }

    public WebserviceReq getWebserviceReq() {
        return req;
    }
}
```

usage:

1)

```
WebserviceReq req = new WebserviceReq();
req.addPerson(XMLUtil.createPerson("test", "2014-01-01", address));
req.send();
```

2)

```
WebserviceReq req = new WebserviceReq();
XMLUtil.addPerson(req, "test", "2014-01-01", address);
req.send();
```

3)

```
WebserviceReq req = new WebserviceReq();
XMLService service = new XMLService(req);
service.createPerson("test", "2014-01-01", address);
service.getWebserviceReq();
req.send();
```

Which approach would you prefer if there is not only a person object to be constructed for the xml request, but lots of more parts that you are trying to encapsulate somehow, so that not a single class is blowing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done and used many times to great effect is the following...

Create a set of classes for each of the element types in XML - this to include the following...

Node - Base class for all elements.  Supports setting and getting of attributes.
Leaf - base class for any element containing a value (simple elements)
Branch - a collection of Leaf elements.  Children are accessed by index.
Entity - A Branch that allows keyed access to its children.

As opposed to how you are doing it now, where you have a bean named Person which has private variables and requires code to set and get each value, you would use an Entity instance and add leaf instances to it, for example...

```
Entity person = new Entity("Person");
person.add(new Leaf<String>("FirstName", "Rodney"));
person.add(new Leaf<String>("LastName", "Barbati"));
```

The power here comes from adding the ability of the base classes to write themselves out as XML.  This gives you the ability to quickly create new types and not have to write code to convert them to XML.

You can also make this completely transparent by deriving the person class from Entity and adding the child elements in its constructor.  I would also advise you to add a validation method that checks for the existence and correct formatting of each required child.

There are classes provided in Java for dealing with XML elements but they are somewhat cumbersome and not easily used.  You could consider either wrapping them or deriving from them to make them more easily used.

The above gives you the ability to output XML easily without requiring boilerplate code - if you marry it with a custom SAX parser that can construct a given class for a given element, you have a complete basis for high speed, streaming XML services that can support new data types almost instantly with very little lines of code - often none at all.

If you find yourself writing custom code to output any XML structure, understand that you don't have to - there is a better solution.

BTW:  The above classes would lend themselves quite nicely to defining the data structures in Spring.

Good Luck,

Rodney Barbati

Comment: Good idea in general, but: I have the webservice classes autogenerated according to provided wsdl from the webservice. Usig your approach, I'd have to further create one wrapper class for generated class I want to use...

Comment: Yes that is true - you will also have to write a new class anyways in order to provide any functionality because your generated classes won't actually have any functionality in them.  In those classes you will have to refer to all of the data members of the generated classes you work with explicitly.